# HTML5 VIDEO TAG NOT WORKING IN RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, video

So I used the HTML video code 
`<video controls="controls"><source src="/assests/videos/HeatherBeem.mp4"/>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>`. It shows the video template but doesn't link to the video file in app/assets/videos.

[image: This is the code in my activeadmin page]

[image: This is what it looks like in the browser]

The first image is my HTML code with the video tag highlighted in activeadmin.
The second image is how it looks like on the browser. It shows the video template without the video. I suspect it's not linking to the video tag. Is something wrong with the code??

I also double checked the - the video file is in app/assets/video/HeatherBeem.mp4

Would love some help. Thanks

Comment: I think this is most certainly a path issue. Load the video in your browser window, by itself, and tell me the URL. Then, on your page, right-click the `video` tag and tell me what path it is loading. Also, you're running the app in a dev environment, correct?

Comment: <source src="/public/videos/video.MP4 "/> This is my updated src.

Comment: https://pascology.herokuapp.com/public/videos/video.MP4 this is the route when i right click and load in the browser. And yes I am running it in the dev env.

Comment: Please update your question with all this updated and additional information. Also, add in all of the combinations that you have tried that did not work

Comment: sure on it. @WesFoster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys I found the problem. I added `config.assets.compile = true` and     `config.serve_static_files = true` to my **development.rb** file in config/env/dev.rb and then i run `$ RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and it worked.

I tried all the suggestions you gave and they worked perfectly once those two were in the development.rb. the `config.serve_static_files = true`serves all assets in the public/assets folder. Thanks guys. You're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on my project by setting the source url without the folder "/videos" as shown below:

```
<video controls="controls">
  <source src="assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: I tried yours and it still didn't work. what other file in rails might cause this? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: found the answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

if you're link is with Rails convention and no naming was made to the pipeline

the problem you is a typo.

it's assets... not assests

than you can make sure you are pointing to the right end point

Comment: thanks for the correction. I corrected the typo but it still didn't work. I checked the route again. It points to app/assets/videos . Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you could try and use the helper method rails created for this serve

create a folder in your public folder named videos and use 

video_path('filename.mp4')

reference 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper/video_path

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a comment with a guess

Comment: @WesFoster found the answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: @FedeSc found the ans. Thanks alot